# Cannot create custom rule for dbManager in Yii2

Tags: php, sql-server, yii2, rbac

I am trying to create custom rule for my Yii2 app, but I there is some kind of problem when I run migration. This is how my migration looks:

```
    $manager = $auth->createRole('manager');
    $auth->add($manager);

    //Allow manager to create work items for own employees.
    $manager_rule = new ManagerRule();
    $auth->add($manager_rule);

    $create_employee_work_item = $auth->createPermission('create_employee_work_item');
    $create_employee_work_item->description = 'Create employee work item';
    $create_employee_work_item->ruleName = $manager_rule->name;

    $auth->add($create_employee_work_item);
    $auth->addChild($manager, $create_employee_work_item);
```

Code from ManagerRule class:

```
namespace app\rbac;
use yii\rbac\Rule;
class ManagerRule extends Rule
{
    public $name = 'isManagerOf';

    public function execute($user, $item, $params)
    {
        return isset($params['user']) ? $params['user']->manager_id === $user : false;
    }
}
```

And when I try to do migration, I have this error.
[image]

This happens here `$auth->add($create_employee_work_item);`

Then I noticed something weird in my auth_rule table.
[image]

I beleive that hex at data column is creating problems, and im not sure that data should be stored in hex format there. Any ideas how to solve it?

I use MSSQL as my DB.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in initial RBAC migration file `m140506_102106_rbac_init.php`

I found that auth_item.data column type was binary:

```
$this->createTable($authManager->ruleTable, [
    'name' => $this->string(64)->notNull(),
    'data' => $this->binary(),
    'created_at' => $this->integer(),
    'updated_at' => $this->integer(),
    'PRIMARY KEY ([[name]])',
], $tableOptions);
```

So I changed it to text:

```
'data' => $this->text(),
```

Comment: This is not a best idea how to deal with it. RBAC uses [`serialize()`](https://www.php.net/serialize) function to save data into the `data` field and this function returns binary. If you handle it as string the data might get corrupted.

Comment: serialize() function does not return binary, it returns string. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: @TomsEglite according to the docs 
**"Returns a string containing a byte-stream representation of value that can be stored anywhere.

Note that this is a binary string which may include null bytes, and needs to be stored and handled as such. For example, serialize() output should generally be stored in a BLOB field in a database, rather than a CHAR or TEXT field. "**.